# Сортировка постов, которые выводятся через ACF

Tags: php, html, wordpress, acf

Новости посажены через ACf:

```html
<?php
        $post_objects = get_field('blog_page');
        if( $post_objects ): ?>
      <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): ?>
      <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex">
        <div class="blog__item">
          <div class="blog__img">
            <img src="<? the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="blog__info">
            <p class="blog__date">
              <? echo get_the_date() ?>
            </p>
            <h2 class="blog__name fz_20 c_dark mb-2">
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <p>
              <? global $post;
                           $content_parts = get_extended( $post->post_content );            
                           echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_parts['main']);  ?>
            </p>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_attr(the_permalink())?>"
              class="blog_permalink permalink_after fw_demi tt_upper c_red fz_14 mr-auto">
              <?php  echo $my_variable['btn_more']; ?>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы они сортировались по дате добавления? Знаю, что сортировка настраивается через 'order'       => 'DESC или ASC', но не могу понять как ее вставить в этот код. Буду благодарен за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по вопросу у вас в переменной `$post_objects` храниться массив с объектами post, поэтому вы можете отсортировать сами значения в массиве. ниже два варианта сортировки по возрастанию и по убыванию

```
// ASC
usort($post_objects, function( $a, $b ) {
   return strtotime($a->post_date) <=> strtotime($b->post_date);
} );

// DESC
usort($post_objects, function( $a, $b ) {
   return -( strtotime($a->post_date) <=> strtotime($b->post_date) );
} );
```